# how to override an Ajax function in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have to override update_order_review function from class-wc-ajax.php and disable this two code:

```
WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
WC()->cart->calculate_totals();
```

how should I do that,also here is class-wc-ajax.php :

[class-wc-ajax.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/trunk/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-ajax.php)

Comment: Not sure why you wanna remove/disable those 2 function calls, but you can either edit the code files or you can unhook the ajax callback function and recreate similar function in your child theme with changes and hook it again with same ajax action.

Comment: how can I unhook the ajax callback function ?